# How to return true value after function calling 3 times

Tags: jquery, html, function

//this is hide function for hide all error reports

```
function hide_errors(){
    $(".error_orient").hide();
    $(".error_short").hide();
    $(".error_master").hide();
  }
```

//error checking function

```
  function error_check(data,_class){
    if(data.val()=="" || data.val()==0){
      data.parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
      $(_class).show();
      return true;
    }
    else
      data.parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
      $(_class).hide();
      return false;
  }
```

//Record Add New Record after check empty/duplicate

```
  $("#btnSave").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    _error_check = false;

    var orientation_name = $('#orientation_name');
    var short_code = $('#short_code');
    var master_select = $('#ori_master');
    hide_errors();

    _error_check = error_check(orientation_name,'.error_orient');
    _error_check = error_check(short_code,'.error_short');
    _error_check = error_check(master_select,'.error_master');

    //Add New Record
    if(_error_check==false){
      $.ajax({
----
----
      }); 
    //end Ajax
    }
  })
  //End function
```

when 3rd function return true value at the same time run ajax..
But I need all functions true at the time run ajax..
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `&=` to AND the values together:

```
_error_check = true;
_error_check &= !error_check(orientation_name,'.error_orient');
_error_check &= !error_check(short_code,'.error_short');
_error_check &= !error_check(master_select,'.error_master');

if (_error_check == true)
```

Using && or &= says 'these must all pass', so the result of 'error_check' must be true==pass.  As it's not (it's true==failed), you need to invert the result, or change it so that it does.

Changing the names can make it clearer, eg

```
function haserror(data, cls) {
    // return true if it has an error
```

or

```
function passescheck(data, cls) {
    // return true if it passes
```

You can use either.  The above uses `&=` to say "all 3 have passed", but you could equally say

"any 1 has failed"

```
var has_failed = false;
has_failed |= haserror(orientation_name,'.error_orient');
has_failed |= haserror(short_code,'.error_short');
has_failed |= haserror(master_select,'.error_master');

if (has_failed == false)  // then has passed
```

or "all 3 have passed"

```
var has_passed = true;
has_passed &= passescheck(orientation_name,'.error_orient');
has_passed &= passescheck(short_code,'.error_short');
has_passed &= passescheck(master_select,'.error_master');

if (has_passed == true)  // then has passed
```

Comment: Because your `error_check` returns true == error and && / &= only really works true = no error, so need to invert the function result.

Comment: Your requirement is that "all 3 functions are true" - yet you check if they're false, so a little confusing.

Comment: Tahnk you very very so much

Comment: How to write multi Ajaxs by using functions?

Answer (score 1):

Change the three lines like this:

```
_error_check = error_check(orientation_name,'.error_orient');
_error_check = _error_check && error_check(short_code,'.error_short');
_error_check = _error_check && error_check(master_select,'.error_master');
```

And change the `if` expression to

```
if(_error_check){
```

Using `&&` with `false` values return `false`. So, your AJAX will work only if all of these return `true`.